# Projection for a map covering 2 UTM zones

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography, utm

I know similar questions have been asked about this already, but I would like to check something specifically... I have a copy of a published 1:1m map of Ivory Coast which states (in the legend) that it's projected in UTM30N, WGS 84. The problem I am wondering about is that the map spans zones UTM30N and UTM29N, so doesn't this mean that there is likely to be quite a lot of distortion across the map? Wouldn't lat-lon have been a more appropriate choice for such a map? I'm intrigued and would like to know what others think, because it's an official, published map and its authors must surely know more than I do about this!

Comment: No, a geographic coordinate system is not likely to be better than a projected CS for such a small area. Choice of projection is surely a jugement call on the part of the cartographer or mapping agency, but not something that be questioned in GIS SE, since it's too *opinion-based* to provide a correct answer. Once you have sufficient reputation you could ask this in our [chat], though it's not a heavily utilized feature.

Comment: If you "know similar questions have been asked about this already" what were they?  Please provide links to them.

Comment: Opinion-based? 1. People like to measure in meters or feet rather than degrees and it's lot easier to measure distances or areas;. 2. Map scale is more consistent across the map than it would be in a GCS; 3. UTM conserves shapes/angles so data looks "better"; 4. Publisher? Some agencies just have a standard that UTM is used for almost everything.